# Stone block with red veins and a black spot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I stumbled on this stone block at Z-16 that illuminates some light. It has red/pink veins and a dark black spot about 1/16 the size of a single block. I cannot mine it with my iron pickaxe. I tried googling it but cannot find anything related. I have the Soartex texture pack and the latest FTB unleashed installed. Anyone knows what this is and what it yields when mined?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ChrisF Sure, done.

Comment: Does that pack have NEI or anything like that? If so, I would search through the pages until you find the item. It might take time, but it would ultimately give you the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah i have NEI, but there are loads of pages. I will look when i have the time for it.

Comment: It's time consuming, but it is a sure-fire way to find the answer. I use that method any time I come across an item I don't know and can't pick up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of hive is called a [Deep Hive](http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/Hive_Bee) and it contains [Attuned Bees](http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/Attuned_Bee). It is added by the [Magic Bees](http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/Magic_Bees) mod (formerly referred to as Thaumic Bees). Here's the default texture:

[image]

As with all beehives, you collect the bees from it by breaking it with a [Scoop](http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/Getting_Started_%28Forestry%29#Scoop_Recipe).

Comment: Yeah i found another one as well and wanted to add this too. Since you named the hive, the bees it contains and the mod they are in i grant you the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of the Beehives.  Use a scoop on it.  Make a scoop by placing sticks in a crafting table in the shape of a Y or a 2 prong fork, and place a wool block in the middle of the top part.

Comment: What at Z16? Too bad i killed it with a diamond pickaxe, nothing dropped :/

Comment: Do you have the seed for that world?  Could try to regenerate and revisit the coordinates

Comment: This is without a doubt a bee-hive, although which one I'm unsure.

Comment: @ender Beehives do not have a spot like that on the side, i compared it to a couple of hives but the regular bee-hives have more of a keyhole hole in them. I located it between redstone blocks and it was completely surrounded by solid blocks.

Comment: @MennoGouw I downloaded the latest soartex fanver which has the same texture for stone as in your image, but it has no HD beehive textures, and the soartex for FTB Unleashed is all low res, the spots on the sides are 6px tall.  In your image the spot is roughly 20px tall.  The only beehives that should be available at that depth are Rock Hives, and they can spawn surrounded by stone

Comment: @MennoGouw yes they do, I am sorry to be such a jerk about this, but flat out, your wrong, I'm not, that's a beehive, there is no argument. Not all beehives look like your standard hives, some look a little different, including this bell shaped hole on the side.

Comment: @ender You do not have to be a jerk about it imo. I was not trying to state anything but clear up some things by saying it looks different then above ground bee-hives. Please post as an answer with your source information since i am still grasping in the dark about this mysterious block.

Answer (score 2):

This is a beehive. I have personally found, and harvested these blocks many times. I have never been able to (ever) find any information as to why these particular hives look different, or if extra bees or thaumatic bees has any part in why they look different. Next time I find one, I'll screenshot myself breaking it to get bees.

[image: Bee Hive Unbroken]

[image: Bee Hive Broken]

For the sake of acuracy, this hive was found in the Twilight Forest, in a cave, and it gave me an Attuned Princess.

Comment: You probably would need to put a source for this quick.

Comment: Normally I'm all for sources, but I have none at this time. As stated, I'll provide one as soon as I find one, until then my [minecraft] badge is enough as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Ender How would you break it to get bee's?

Comment: Same as any other bee-hive, with a scoop